# Как сделать, чтобы ViewPager не залазил на TabLayout?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mindzone.wireframetodemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   .......
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Как один из вариантов - поместить `ViewPager` и `TabLayout` на `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ...>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...
        />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           ...
        />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Либо `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
...>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        ...
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabs" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            ...
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: нет, нужно это сделать средствами CoordinatorLayaut.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentStart="true" - что это значит?

Comment: @Igor, так а чем добавление `RelativeLayout` в `CoordinatorLayout` не его средства? Или вообще все описать как необходимо в другой xml и сделать `include`